# Beautiful Soup and extracting a div and its contents by ID

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup.find("tagName", { "id" : "articlebody" })
```

Why does this NOT return the `<div id="articlebody"> ... </div>` tags and stuff in between? It returns nothing. And I know for a fact it exists because I'm staring right at it from

```
soup.prettify()
```

`soup.find("div", { "id" : "articlebody" })` also does not work.

(**EDIT:** I found that BeautifulSoup wasn't correctly parsing my page, which probably meant the page I was trying to parse isn't properly formatted in SGML or whatever)

Comment: (To your EDIT, this question still has value as a reusable resource to others, even if the parser doesn't work on your particular page)

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You should post your example document, because the code works fine:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div id="articlebody"> ... </div></body></html')
>>> soup.find("div", {"id": "articlebody"})
<div id="articlebody"> ... </div>
```

Finding `<div>`s inside `<div>`s works as well:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div><div id="articlebody"> ... </div></div></body></html')
>>> soup.find("div", {"id": "articlebody"})
<div id="articlebody"> ... </div>
```

Comment: my example document is enormous. i'm tracking down the problem - i think this doesn't work on divs of divs. I did a count of how many divs are in the document with print len(soup('div')) which resulted in 10, and i can CLEARLY see more than 10 divs with firebug. so i think it just can't find divs inside divs, so i need to narrow things down wrapper by wrapper.

Comment: Well, then it's impossible to answer your question, crystal balls are not a reliable way of debugging. :)

Comment: I tried this code. the div has <embed> and I 'cant print the embed inside it.

Comment: or more simply [`div = soup.find(id="articlebody")`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22410466/4279)

Comment: or `soup.find('div', id='articlebody')`

Comment: I'd just point out when installing, install `pip install beautifulsoup4` because command without the 4 installs version 3 instead of 4. https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 127):

To find an element by its `id`:

```
div = soup.find(id="articlebody")
```

Comment: Maybe this is for an old version?

`Exception: TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: @boatcoder it works with the latest version (4.11.1)

Comment: https://replit.com/@zed1/bs4-find

Comment: You get `TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments` when you call `find()` on a string, not a parsed BS object.

Answer (score 49):

Beautiful Soup 4 supports most [CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) with the [`.select()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), therefore you can use an [`id` selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) such as:

```
soup.select('#articlebody')
```

If you need to specify the element's type, you can add a [type selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) before the `id` selector:

```
soup.select('div#articlebody')
```

The `.select()` method will return a collection of elements, which means that it would return the same results as the following [`.find_all()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) example:

```
soup.find_all('div', id="articlebody")
# or
soup.find_all(id="articlebody")
```

If you only want to select a single element, then you could just use the [`.find()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
soup.find('div', id="articlebody")
# or
soup.find(id="articlebody")
```

Answer (score 17):

I think there is a problem when the 'div' tags are too much nested. I am trying to parse some contacts from a facebook html file, and the Beautifulsoup is not able to find tags "div" with class "fcontent".

This happens with other classes as well. When I search for divs in general, it turns only those that are not so much nested.

The html source code can be any page from facebook of the friends list of a friend of you (not the one of your friends). If someone can test it and give some advice I would really appreciate it.

This is my code, where I just try to print the number of tags "div" with class "fcontent":

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
f = open('/Users/myUserName/Desktop/contacts.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f) 
list = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'fcontent'})
print len(list)
```

Comment: Could be a bug. Log an issue perhaps?

Answer (score 9):

Most probably because of the default beautifulsoup parser has problem. Change a different parser, like 'lxml' and try again.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I used `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, parser="html.parser")`

Answer (score 8):

In the beautifulsoup source this line allows divs to be nested within divs; so your concern in lukas' comment wouldn't be valid.

```
NESTABLE_BLOCK_TAGS = ['blockquote', 'div', 'fieldset', 'ins', 'del']
```

What I think you need to do is to specify the attrs you want such as

```
source.find('div', attrs={'id':'articlebody'})
```

Answer (score 5):

have you tried `soup.findAll("div", {"id": "articlebody"})`?

sounds crazy, but if you're scraping stuff from the wild, you can't rule out multiple divs...

Answer (score 5):

I used:

```
soup.findAll('tag', attrs={'attrname':"attrvalue"})
```

As my syntax for find/findall; that said, unless there are other optional parameters between the tag and attribute list, this shouldn't be different.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code fragment

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(:"index.html")
titleList = soup.findAll('title')
divList = soup.findAll('div', attrs={ "class" : "article story"})
```

As you can see I find all  tags and then I find all  tags with class="article" inside

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me also while trying to scrape Google.
I ended up using pyquery.
Install:

```
pip install pyquery
```

Use:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery    
pq = PyQuery('<html><body><div id="articlebody"> ... </div></body></html')
tag = pq('div#articlebody')
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Id` property is always uniquely identified. That means you can use it directly without even specifying the element. Therefore, it is a plus point if your elements have it to parse through the content.

```
divEle = soup.find(id = "articlebody")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'your_url'
session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get(url)

# if element with id "articlebody" is dynamic, else need not to render
resp.html.render()

soup = bs(resp.html.html, "lxml")
soup.find("div", {"id": "articlebody"})
```

Answer (score -3):

```
soup.find("tagName",attrs={ "id" : "articlebody" })
```

Comment: provide more explanation to your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: bad answer: `TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments`