# Searching for strings when dumping a webpage

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

I am dumping a webpage with requests, and I need to search for a string inside the code. I need to get the div fields and search for a certain value.

```
import requests, pprint
page = requests.get('')
tree = (page.content)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(tree)
```

Comment: Use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for such things - it's a HTML parser.

Refer more at: [Beautiful Soup and extracting a div and its contents by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136267/beautiful-soup-and-extracting-a-div-and-its-contents-by-id)

import requests, pprint
import bs4

```
page = requests.get('')
tree = (page.content)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div id="articlebody"> ... </div></body></html')
divs = soup.find_all("div")
texts = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("div")]
```