# How to get text of anchor tags only if it is inside paragraph using beautiful soup?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the scraped data with beautiful soup. What I need is get all the visible data that is all the data in the article, and h1. Most of the times article data has text with a embedded in it. Something like "I am a "href/good_boy" in my class". Now I want that 'a' tag only if it is inside the paragraph. Following is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import json
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from queue import Queue
    from threading import Thread
    options = Options()
    #data = []
    our_urls = []
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


    def foo():
        global our_urls
        with open('input_backup.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            global our_urls
            our_urls = data['urls']
            return our_urls


    def scraper_worker(q):
     try:
        while not q.empty():
            url = q.get()
            #print(url)
            driver = url[2]
            r = driver.get(url[1])
            last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

            while True:
                # Scroll down to bottom
                # make_true=False
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

                # Wait to load page
                time.sleep(10)

                # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
                new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                # soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
                # print("inside loop" + driver.current_url + "\n\t" + soup.get_text())
                if new_height == last_height:
                    # If heights are the same it will exit the function
                    break
                last_height = new_height
            driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")

            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            whitelist = [
                        'p', 'h1','a'
                     ]

            blackList = [   '[document]',
        'noscript','div',
        'footer',
        'html',
        'meta',
        'head',
        'input',
        'script',]
            text_elements = [t for t in soup.find_all(text=True) if t.parent.name in whitelist]
            print("\n\t" + driver.current_url + "\n\t")
            print(text_elements)
            #page = pyquery(r.text)
            #data = page("#data").text()
            # do something with data
            driver.quit()
            q.task_done()
     except:
         pass

    # Create a queue and fill it
    urls = foo()
    #print(urls)
    mlen = len(urls)
    q = Queue()
    #for x in urls:
      #q.put(x)
    for i in range(len(urls)):
          # need the index and the url in each queue item.
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=options)
        q.put((i, urls[i],driver))
    #map(q.put, urls)

    # Create 5 scraper workers
    for i in range(3):
        t = Thread(target=scraper_worker, args=(q, ))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    #print("waiting for queue to complete", jobs.qsize(), "tasks")
    q.join()

    print("all tasks completed")
```

Following is the reference url
[Sample url](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/tethers-unlimited-says-terminator-tape-004011438.html)

and here is the output

> ['Mail', 'News', 'Finance', 'Sports', 'Entertainment', 'Search', 'Mobile', 'More', 'Sign in', ' react-text: 10 ', 'Finance Home', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 20 ', 'Watchlists', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 23 ', 'My Portfolio', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 26 ', 'Screeners', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 29 ', 'Premium', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 32 ', 'Markets', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 35 ', 'Industries', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 38 ', 'Personal Finance', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 41 ', 'Videos', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 44 ', 'News', ' /react-text ', ' react-text: 47 ', 'Tech', ' /react-text ', 'S&P 500', 'Dow 30', 'Nasdaq', 'Russell 2000', 'Crude Oil', 'Tethers Unlimited says ‘Terminator Tape’ is speeding up a satellite’s descent as intended', 'GeekWire', 'Bothell, Wash.-based ', 'Tethers Unlimited', ' says “Terminator Tape,” an experimental tether-based system designed to drag satellites down from orbit, is working the way it’s supposed to.', 'Georgia Tech’s Prox-1 satellite', 'sent into orbit last June on a SpaceX Falcon Heavy rocket', 'said in a news release', 'collaborating with Millennium Space Systems, TriSept and Rocket Lab on a test mission known as DragRacer', 'Hoyt told Space News', 'LEO Knight servicing robot', 'Tethers Unlimited joins forces with TriSept to test system for reducing orbital debris', 'Tethers Unlimited works on technologies for ‘LEO Knight’ satellite servicing robot', 'Tethers Unlimited says two-way radio for small satellites has aced first orbital test', 'Tethers Unlimited lifts the curtain on mesh networking system for small satellites', 'Kolte Patil - Ivy Nia', 'Ad', 'Maruti Suzuki', 'Ad', 'Fateheducation', 'Ad', 'hear.com', 'Ad']
>   all tasks completed.

So can anyone please help me with,how to get only the text article with header and paragraph in between. I am not getting the desired output like

Bothell, Wash.-based Tethers Unlimited says “Terminator Tape,” an experimental tether-based system designed to drag satellites down from orbit, is working the way it’s supposed to.

```
The notebook-sized Terminator Tape system has been placed on several nanosatellites for testing — including Georgia Tech’s Prox-1 satellite, which was sent into orbit last June on a SpaceX Falcon Heavy rocket. Last September, the system’s 230-foot-long tether was strung out to add to the slight atmospheric drag experienced in low Earth orbit. “We can see from observations by the U.S. Space Surveillance Network that the satellite immediately began deorbiting over 24 times faster,” Tethers Unlimited CEO Rob Hoyt said in a news release.
That’s a good thing: Terminator Tape is meant to address the need to move retired satellites more quickly out of orbit, rather than having them add to the growing space-junk problem. “Instead of remaining in orbit for hundreds or thousands of years, the Prox-1 satellite will fall out of orbit and burn up in the upper atmosphere in under 10 years. … This successful test proves that this lightweight and low-cost technology is an effective means for satellite programs to meet orbital debris mitigation requirements,” Hoyt said.
Tethers Unlimited is currently collaborating with Millennium Space Systems, TriSept and Rocket Lab on a test mission known as DragRacer, due for launch this year. The mission will compare the deorbit rates for two identical satellites, one with Terminator Tape and one without, to characterize the system’s performance more precisely. Hoyt told Space News that in the years ahead, the system could be attached to defunct satellites in orbit using Tethers Unlimited’s planned LEO Knight servicing robot.
```

Comment: You can use bs4 to find the content in HTML code, then extract it. Try this: [Beautiful Soup and extracting a div and its contents by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136267/beautiful-soup-and-extracting-a-div-and-its-contents-by-id). And not related to your question, why you used selenium + bs4? Selenium supports [getting text from element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-web-driver-in-python), while bs4 supports [finding and extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136267/beautiful-soup-and-extracting-a-div-and-its-contents-by-id).

Comment: If you want to crawl data effectively, you should use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) instead.

Comment: I am using it, problem is scraping multiple urls in scrapy is asynchronous and it is overlapping each other as I have to execute scripts like scroll.o scraping, thought bs4 is more easier

Comment: The link you posted contains a generalized class, how about multiple urls.

Comment: I have create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/daoducminh/22a7625175856881ab2e07e251e6d955) for Scrapy using synchronous.

Comment: And about your `generalized class`, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get multiple urls from a file, get all the article like data and header.

Comment: I will use your posted url as an example. If you use selenium: `article = driver.find_element_by_class_name('article').text`. If you use bs4: `article = soup.find('article').text`.

Comment: Exactly my problem. This site has article, but other sites have such data not inside article tag. So its more like text data minus, header,footer and navigation tab nav_links

Comment: Well, the only thing you can do is to find their patterns. Selenium, bs4 or scrapy will only do what you order. In case you want to make them do the job by themselves, you have to use Artificial Intelligence (not sure is Machine Learning or Deep Learning)

Comment: @MinhDao that is chicken or egg situation :) Artificial intelligence for scraping data for a project of artificial intelligence :) . Anyways thank you for all that help,meanwhile trying out the gist code of yours for synchronous data in scrapy. Wondering if I can do it with Queue and threads inside scrapy :) Like create instance of browsers like I am doing right now :)