# Using Python with Beautifulsoup to find span class data-automation-id value

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Could someone please tell me how to use beautifulsoup to extract the value ($100.00) from a data-automation-id="header-account-balance"?  I can see how to find elements by class ([How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)) and id ([Beautiful Soup and extracting a div and its contents by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136267/beautiful-soup-and-extracting-a-div-and-its-contents-by-id)) but don't know how to refine it for a "data-automation-id" value.  I have scraped the following code:

```
<div class="contentContainer_ff3y6tu">
<div class="container_fikviug">
<div class="accountPillForPersonal_fituo0a">
<div class="balanceTextContainer_fu48fjw">
<div class="container_fdoc1b1">
<span class="size14_f7opyze" data-automation-id="header-account-balance">$100.00</span>
</div></div>
<div class="tokenCount_f19lbt28">
<span class="size12_fq5j3k2 CodGray_f1tc10rl bold_f1au7gae">7</span>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example, you can do it this way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<your html here>")
tag = soup.find("span", {"data-automation-id": "header-account-balance"})
value = tag.string
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Dmytro :)